# Everything not working when I did step by step follow Google Sheets API guilding

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

at the first time I tried to use Google Sheets API to get manage some spreadsheets on my Google Drive with the guide in "Complete example" part of that document: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app

Although I made it correct way in every steps, but I alway receive the error: "HTTP ERROR 500" when the PHP run to command:

```
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
```

My project dir structure is:

```
/public_html/api
--- vendor
--- client_secrets.json
--- composer.json
--- composer.lock
--- composer.phar
--- index.php
--- oauth2callback.php
```

I get the vendor dir from this link: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/releases (google-api-php-client-2.0.3_PHP54.zip)

This is the code content in test.waytech.vn/api/index.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();
  echo json_encode($files_list);
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://test.waytech.vn/api/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

This is the code content in test.waytech.vn/api/oauth2callback.php:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://test.waytech.vn/api/oauth2callback.php');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (! isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
} else {
  $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
  $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
  $redirect_uri = 'http://test.waytech.vn/api';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

I did not sleep 2 nights to resolve this problem, but cannot find any solutions still now.

Comment: Check this [SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234668/http-500-internal-server-error-when-using-google-api-php-client-on-a-remote-se), it might help.